# Calculate the residue of $f(z)=\frac{z^3e^{iz}}{z^4+16}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am solving a problem involving contour integration using the Residue theorem and I have to calculate the residue of $f(z)=\frac{z^3e^{iz}}{z^4+16}$

It is clear that a pole of $f$ is $2e^{i\pi/4}$. Since it is a pole of order $1$:

$\mathrm{Res}({2e^{i\pi/4}},f(z))
=\lim_{z\to2e^{i\pi/4}}(z-2e^{i\pi/4})\frac{z^3e^{iz}}{z^4+16}$

How do I compute that limit? The result should be $\frac{z^3 e^{iz}}{4z^3}$ for $z=2e^{i\pi/4}$

Answer (score 5):

Where $z_0$ is a singularity of $f(z)$ and $f(z)=\frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$:
$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \left(z-z_0\right) \cdot \frac{h(z)}{g(z)}= \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{h(z)}{g'(z)}$$

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: It's more-or-less the definition of derivative.

Comment: @JohnKeeper Think of $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{z-z_0}{g(z)}$ as the reciprocal of $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0} = g'(z)$.  I'm not sure if this is the proper derivation, but this should be valid because $g(z_0)=0$.