# Residues of $f(z)=\frac{z^3\sin(z)}{z^4+16}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

For $f(z)=\frac{z^3e^{iz}}{z^4+16}$ I'm unsure if I'm computing the residues correctly. If my contour is semi-circular in the upper half-plane, there are two poles at $2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$ and $2e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}$. So for the first residue I write :

$$\mathrm{Res}({2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}},f(z))=\lim_{z\to2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}}{(z-2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}})\, {\frac{z^3e^{iz}}{(z-2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})(z-2e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}})(z-2e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}})(z-2e^{\frac{-3i\pi}{4}})}}$$

So clearly I can cancel the first factor, however I'm unsure how this arrives at the fact written [at this MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725371/calculate-the-residue-of-fz-fracz3eizz416). Continuing this calculation we have :

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{Res}({2e^\frac{i\pi}{4}},f(z))&=\frac{(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})^3e^{i{(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})}}}{(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}-2e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}})(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} - 2e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}})(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}-2e^{-\frac{3i\pi}{4}})}\\&=\frac{8e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}e^{i(2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})}}{4i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})(8\sqrt2e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})}\\&=\frac{\left(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})\right)e^{i(\sqrt2+i\sqrt2)}}{4i(\sqrt2+i\sqrt2)}\end{align}$$

Is this correct? Is there an easier method to do this residue - other than the linked fact? Finally is there a way to easily do the other pole without redoing the whole calculation?

Comment: Mathematica indicates there are 4 poles with the following residues: $$\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Pole} & \text{Residue} \\
 -2 \sqrt[4]{-1} & -\frac{1}{4} \sin \left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right) \\
 2 \sqrt[4]{-1} & \frac{1}{4} \sin \left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right) \\
 -2 (-1)^{3/4} & -\frac{1}{4} \sin \left(2 (-1)^{3/4}\right) \\
 2 (-1)^{3/4} & \frac{1}{4} \sin \left(2 (-1)^{3/4}\right) \\
\end{array}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a trick that I find useful to simplify the denominator:

$a^4-b^4 = (a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ ab^2 + b^3)$

$z^4+16 = (z-2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}})(z^3 + z^2(2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}})+ z(4e^{i\frac {2\pi}{4}})+8e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}})$

$\lim_\limits{z\to 2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}}}(z^3 + z^2(2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}})+ z(4e^{i\frac {2\pi}{4}})+8e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}}) = 32e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}}$

Which will nicely cancel with the $z^3$ term in the numerator when we calculate the limit for the residual.

$Res(2e^{i\frac {\pi}{4}},f(z)) = \frac {\sin(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})}{4}$

Similarly, we can also say:

$z^4+16 = (z-2e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}})(z^3 + z^2(2e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}})+ z(4e^{i\frac {6\pi}{4}})+8e^{i\frac {9\pi}{4}})$

$\lim_\limits{z\to 2e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}}}(z^3 + z^2(2e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}})+ z(4e^{i\frac {6\pi}{4}})+8e^{i\frac {9\pi}{4}}) = 32e^{i\frac {9\pi}{4}}$

$Res(2e^{i\frac {3\pi}{4}},f(z)) = \frac {\sin(e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}})}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Your computation looks fine. I don't think there is an easier way to proceed.